# Refresh imageview in listview without blocking the UI

Tags: android-listview, android-imageview, android-view, android

I have a `ListView` in which I am display Facebook friend's Image and name.Right now what I am doing is that I am showing 7 friends at once and have a load more button that displays next 7 and so on.   [image: My Friend's Listview]

Now what I want do is show all the names but with a default pic in the `ImageView` and refresh only if it is showing on the screen without blocking the UI. eg If user is seeing Mr X on the screen then only I get his picture and show it in the `ImageView` without blocking the UI.

Comment: did you even search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: He probably did try to search for it but didn't know the proper term, "lazy load".

Comment: I tried to search but I didn't know what its called. Nonetheless its done. Thanks man.